# adding argument via constructor or method

Tags: design-patterns, language-agnostic, code-cleanup

I have these validators classes

```
interface Validator {
     bool Validate(string value,object options)
}

class NumberValidator extends Validator {}
class EmailValidator extends Validator {}
class RangeValidator extends Validator {}
...
```

as you can see that the `options` are passed on the call to the `Validate` method. but I was wondering if it's better to have the `options` argument to be passed via constructor instead of the `Validate` method? (from CleanCode perspective).

so the interface and my implementation classes will be like this:

```
interface Validator {
    bool Validate(string value)
}

class SomeValidator extends Validator {
     private object options;
     public SomeValidator(object options) {...}
     public bool Validate(string value) {...}
}

...
```

I sense that having the `options` on the constructor will be better, but honestly, I don't have a reason why it's better.

Answer (score 2):

If by *CleanCode* you're referring to Robert C. Martin's œuvre, you may also want to consider the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID). Here, the [Dependency Inversion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) seems particularly relevant.

As Martin puts it in APPP,

> clients [...] own the abstract interfaces

This means that you design interfaces from the perspective of client code, rather than based on the implementing code.

Is it a requirement that clients can pass an `options` argument at run time? If so, include it in the interface definition.

If clients don't care about `options` at run time, then it shouldn't be part of the interface. By elimination, then, you'll have to make it part of the constructor.

Comment: I was thinking of having `ValidatorFactory` which will create validator instance based on type and assign the options on constructor invocation, so the options will by dynamic and changed on runtime.
thanks for you answer :)

Answer (score 1):

If it's convenient for client code to either, for any particular class  `SomeValidator`, have...

1. one instance where the same options will be applied to every
   `Validate` call, or
2. many instances constructed with different options values and
   find the right `SomeValidator` to use for each validation,

...then having options as a constructor argument makes sense.  In these cases, the constructed object instances effectively become "`SomeValidatorWithSpecificOptions`" objects - doing as specific type of validation for their lifetime.

If, on the other hand, it's more convenient/practical to ask the same `SomeValidator` object to use different options during specific `Validate` calls, then having options be an argument to the `Validate` function makes sense.

You can also do a hybrid approach where the constructor takes a default options value, and the `Validate` call can be passed overriding options or not.

What's best depends entirely on the needs of client code.